# Sacar campo a través de FK en Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Tengo un Django Admin con los modelos y CRUDS montados, ahora bien, me gustaría poder sacar el nombre de un modelo dentro de otro a través del modelo que tienen en común, es decir, tengo un modelo `POI`, otro `POITxt` que están relacionados, la cosa es que tengo otro modelo `PHOTO` que tiene la `id` de `POI`, pero me gustaría dentro del formulario de admin de `PHOTO` que me saliera el campo `PoiTxt_name` de esta manera sabrán el nombre del `POI` que están subiendo la foto.

Como se supone que es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Poi(models.Model):
    poi_id = models.AutoField(db_column='POI_id', primary_key=True)
    poi_latitude = models.CharField(db_column='POI_latitude', max_length=100)
    poi_longitude = models.CharField(db_column='POI_longitude', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'POI'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.pk)

class Photo(models.Model):
    pho_id = models.AutoField(db_column='PHO_id', primary_key=True)
    pho_url = models.ImageField(db_column='PHO_url', upload_to='media/documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    poi = models.ForeignKey(Poi, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='POI_id')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'PHOTO'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.pho_url)


class PoiTxt(models.Model):
    pot_id = models.AutoField(db_column='POT_id', primary_key=True)
    poi = models.ForeignKey(Poi, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='POI_id')
    lan = models.ForeignKey(Language, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='LAN_id')
    pot_name = models.CharField(db_column='POT_name', max_length=100)
    pot_shortdescription = models.TextField(db_column='POT_shortDescription')
    pot_description = models.TextField(db_column='POT_description')
    pot_type = models.CharField(db_column='POT_type', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'POI_TXT'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.pot_name
```

Archivo `admin.py`:

```
class PoiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['poi_id', 'poi_latitude', 'poi_longitude']

    class Meta:
        model = Poi

class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['pho_id', 'pho_url', 'poi']
    form = PhotoForm

    class Meta:
        model = Photo

class PoiTxtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['pot_id', 'poi_id', 'lan', 'pot_name', 'pot_shortdescription', 'pot_description', 'pot_type']

    class Meta:
        model = PoiTxt
```

Y de paso si alguien sabe como hacer multisubida lo agradecería mucho. Ya que cada `POI` puede tener `N` fotos.

**EDITO:**

La idea es que 1 `POI` tenga `N POITXT` (idiomas) y que `1 POI` tenga `N PHOTOS`.

Y que desde el CMS puedan subir muchas fotos eligiendo a que `POI` se asigna y pudiendo ver el nombre de dicho `POI` (`POI->POITXT->pot_name`) dentro de la vista.

Para que sea usable, ya que como lo tengo ahora pueden hacerlo pero solo ven la id del `POI` y así no es cómodo para el usuario.

Otro tema es la multisubida, ya que tiene que poder tener N `PHOTOS`.

Captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZO:**

He probado el `OneToOneField` y ahora al tener más de 1 `POITXT` me saca el siguiente error.

```
get() returned more than one PoiTxt -- it returned 4!
```

La cosa es que he probado a ponerle un `return objeto[0]` y sigue dándome el mismo error, cual sería la manera de filtrarlo?

Código:

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['pho_id', 'pho_url', 'poi', 'poi_info']
    form = PhotoForm

    def poi_info(self, instance):
        poi_text = instance.poi.poitxt.pot_name
        return poi_text[0]

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
```

Alguien sabe porque?

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que como tu modelo de PHOTO solo tiene relación a tu modelo de POI, y POI_TXT tiene un foreignkey con POI, eso quiere decir que POI tiene MUCHOS POI_TXT por lo que PHOTO tiene MUCHOS POI_TXT tambien, si mal no recuerdo lo maximo que puedes mostrar es un select en esa parte de el admin que intentas hacer (list_display), pero en este caso al ser una relacion de uno a muchos, seria un multiselect, que no está soportado... No estoy seguro que tan importante sea que conserves la relacion de tus modelos, pero SOLO si te sirve, podrias cambiar la relacion POI_TXT con POI a OneToOneField, asi podrias acceder asi:

```
list_display = [..., 'poi__poitxt__pot_name', ...]
```

Lo de la multisubida (Supongo que de archivos), es otro tema que deberia tocarse a parte...