# Upload Form Django Error (invalid literal for int() with base 10)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo un formulario con el cual quiero hacer un `insert` en una de los modelos y me da el siguiente error y no soy capaz de saber por que ni debuggear:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
def poiUploader(request):
    title = "Photo Uploader"
    text = "Sube tus fotos"
    pois = PoiTxt.objects.filter(lan__lan_id=1)

    context = {
        "template_title": title,
        "template_text": text,
        "pois": pois,
    }

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        saved_poi = request.POST.get('poiCode', '')
        poi = Poi.objects.filter(poi_id=saved_poi)
        foto = Photo(pho_url=filename, poi=poi)
        foto.save()
        return render(request, 'poi-uploader.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })

    return render_to_response('poi-uploader.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```

Como debería linkear el `poi` con la `photo` con la `ForeignKey`?

*Aquí dejo un link de otro hilo que abrí de otra cosa y esta mi código fuente, [Hilo con mi código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26052/sacar-campo-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-fk-en-django-admin).*

Comment: Podrias por favor añadir los logs de el error, y decirme porque quieres guardar asi los archivos, y no desde un formulario???

Answer (score 1):

A ver, con esto poiCode es un string:

```
saved_poi = request.POST.get('poiCode', '')
poi = Poi.objects.filter(poi_id=saved_poi)
```

Y esto es un int.

```
poi_id = models.AutoField(db_column='POI_id', primary_key=True)
```

Prueba a parsearlo a int y pon el POST que haces y los datos de dentro del POST para qué veamos que más puede ser.